# How can I prevent ng-model from being changed in select based on result of function?

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I have a select drop down menu populated with ng-options. I want to create a pop-up that will require the user to confirm they want to change the selected option before continuing.

So far, I have tried using an ng-change, but that doesn't work because you can't prevent the change (for the purposes of my app, I cannot simply put the value back to what it was before the change in an ng-change function). I have tried ng-click, but this fires when the user clicks on the select box, whereas I want this to fire when the user actually selects one of the options from the select box for UI purposes. I have investigated ng-model-options, but my problem is I cannot seem to get an event to fire when an option is selected.

Code below demonstrating what this select looks like:

```
<select ng-model='uiConfig.selectedInteractionType' ng-options='interactionType for interactionType in uiConfig.interactionTypes'></select>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28047112/1271037

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same requirement, albeit for a different element.  I had a button that was really an anchor tag where I passed in some values, including a URL when the user clicked the button.  I then needed to open an $mddialog modal and let the user cancel or click continue to send them to a redirected site.

What you need is a directive here.  Put the value(s) in $scope.  I used attributes for this:

`restrict: 'A',`

and then in my link function I used
`attributes.$observe`

to pull in my values.
Then use something like this in your directive function:

```
element.on('click' function ($event) {
   $event.preventDefault(); //To stop the event flow.
   $mdDialog.show({
   templateUrl: "path to your modal html document",
   controller: myController,
   clickOutsideToClose: true,
   locals:{
       href: $scope.href,
       myValue: $scope.myValue
   }
```

Using [$locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018656/what-are-locals-in-angularjs-expressions) allows you to pass in the values to the directive.